# TransactionalEventListener is not firing even with fallbackExecution set to true

Tags: spring-boot, event-listener

I have a local library that is integrated as a maven dependency in my project.
The library publishes an event and listen to it by itself.

Code where the event is being published:

```
public void send(String pushDestination, String message) {
    MessagePush msgPush = new MessagePush(pushDestination, Collections.singletonList(message));
    this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(msgPush);
}
```

Following is the piece of code where the library is listening to the event:

```
@TransactionalEventListener(
    phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT,
    fallbackExecution = true
)
public <T> void transactionEventListener(MessagePush msgPush) throws PushException {
    // Some logging here
    this.push(msgPush);
}
```

So how the code is expected to work is that the code in my project should call `send` method which will publish an event with `MessagePush`. That event should be listened by `transactionEventListener` and should call `push` in-turn.

In my code the `send` method is **not** called with in transaction boundaries. But though the flag `fallbackExecution` is set in the `TransactionalEventListener` annotation, still the method `transactionEventListener` is not fired.

To dig a bit what I did is that I created a listener in my project that listens to the library event and that is working perfectly fine:

```
@EventListener
public void onMessageReceive(MessagePush msgPush) {
    log.info("Message received inside DemoEventListener: {}", new Gson().toJson(msgPush));
}
```

Is there a way to effectively debug this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the problem lied in my project's setup.
The application didn't had transaction management in the active spring context at all.

Since `TransactionalEventListener` is part of spring transactions, transaction management should be available in the context to make it working.

Adding following dependency in my pom solve the problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
</dependency>
```